# A way to do stuff with files in git's staging/commit area without using the full path?

Tags: git

So lets imagine that I have some files in staging area like so:

```
#   modified:   application/controllers/controller.php
#   modified:   application/views/protected_views/some_view.php
#   modified:   less/style.less
```

So if I want to for example view diff on just the controller.php I need to run this command:

```
# git diff application/controllers/controller.php
```

I wonder if the is a way (maybe some option to pass)to tell git to only look for files in staging area? So I could run something like:

```
# git diff controller.php
```

So even though there is no controller.php file in current directory, it would figure out that there is file named controller.php in staging area, and it would automatically do some magic in the background and access the correct file? Obviously situation may arise where 2 files with same name exist, then obviously full/part of the path would be required.

So in short: is there any way to do git stuff with staged files without entering a full path to the file?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to diff all files that are staged and not show other differences:

```
git diff --staged
```

If you want to diff just one file:

```
git diff -- full/path/to/file
```

To diff all files that have a certain name (no matter the directory):

```
git ls-files | grep filename | xargs git diff --
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do what you want to do is to be in the directory that the file is located in. In your example if you are in `PROJECT/application/controllers/`, then `git diff controller.php` would work like you expect.

Comment: Yeah but in this case I need to keep CDing to the directory, which is even more work. I was hoping there is lazy way to do stuff with any given staged file from any directory with just entering the file name.

Comment: Unfortunately, there really is no lazy way to do it. Maybe shell tab completion or text editor => git integration will get you want you want. If you use vim, [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) would probably enable your lazy desires

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff `find . -name controller.php`
```

Note that this relies on controller being in the working tree (not the index/cache/staging area), because `find` doesn't know about git - so @cforbish's answer is better in that aspect.

Actually, building on @cforbish's answer, an `*` can match any path (or fragment) for  `ls-files`:

```
git diff `git ls-files */controller.php`
git diff `git ls-files *troll*`
```